# How Can I obtain the value of variables declared in a private sub from another private sub in Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm using Microsoft Access 2013 and encountered this problem when working in VBA.
Is it possible to pass the value of a variable declared or defined in a private sub to a global variable?
I tried different methods... but none worked

First, I defined and declared the variable inside the private sub I'm using it.
Next, I defined the variable as a public variable and then defined it in that private sub, but when I tried passing its value to a global variable, it returned null. I don't know if it's because it's inside a conditional statement.

```
Option Compare Database
Public recUserID As Long
Option Explicit

Private Sub txtPassword_AfterUpdate()
  Dim db As DAO.Database
  Dim rs As DAO.Recordset 
  Set db = CurrentDb
  Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblUser")

'Check that user is selected/entered
If IsNull(Me.txtUser) Then
    MsgBox "Select User"
Else
    rs.FindFirst "[PersonnelID] = '" & Me.txtUser & "'"

    If rs.NoMatch Then
        MsgBox "User does not exist, please enter correct ID"
    Else
        recUserID = rs![UserID]
    End If
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
    gblStudent = recUserID
End Sub
```

It's supposed to pass the value of the variable 'recUserID', which is the ID of the record, to the global variable 'gblStudent', but when debugging, the variable at the 'AfterUpdate of the Form' returns 0

NOTE: The form is bound to a table, and hence, the AfterUpdate function works

Comment: Hello Victor! The answerers are guessing here because you haven't provided enough context for them to reliably see what the problem is. Don't worry about this, it is hard to do for Access questions. Instead, you are getting suggestions on how to solve the problem yourself, which is the best we can do in these circumstances. I hope one of these ideas helps you. If you do find a solution, please post it here for the benefit of future readers.

Comment: If you posted code is in the forms code module, it will not work since that form and code can go out of scope. You have to declare the recUSERID in a standard code module, not a forms one. So all of your above code can remain "as is", but you have to more the recUserID declare out to a standard (non forms) code module, and you be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by calling the value from a recordset in the database, then passing that value to my required global variable

```
Dim state As DAO.Recordset
Set state = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select * from tblStudent")

state.FindFirst "[MatriculationNumber] = '" & Me.txtUser & "'"

gblStudent = state![StudentID]
```

I however placed this code within the AfterUpdate property of a control on the form (txtPassword) to avoid ambiguity

Answer (score 0):

are you even certain that the event is triggered?  Form_AfterUpdate()

put a message box there to sanity check that.

btw; I understand your goal - I myself have evolved away from this method because of the debug challenges... instead my apps always have a Start screen that is always open - - and here is where I place unbound text boxes that serve the same purpose as being a global...but I can make them visible during development to easily see their values.  Something to keep in mind if it fits your project.

Answer (score 0):

First, please read about breakpoints and `Debug.Print`: [Debugging VBA Code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)

`Form_AfterUpdate()` is only triggered for **bound** forms, after saving a record.

A login form is usually **unbound**, i.e. it has no record source. So your function is never executed. You need to find a different event for this.

Comment: I actually bound this form to a log table to keep track of people who log in to the database system.

Comment: @VictorAbuka  I'll interpret Andre's answer and be a bit more explicit:  If you find that `recUserID` is 0 in `Form_AfterUpdate`, then the next logical step should be to **stop and trace through the code where the variable is supposedly set**.  User Debug.Print and then inspect the VBA Immediate Window for its output.  Or put a breakpoint on `recUserID = rs![UserID]` to determine if that line is even called.  The problem is less likely to be with assigning values to variables and more to do with whether or not the code is actually being called at all, or in the order that you think it is.

Comment: I understand, I'll do just that

Answer (score 0):

Many developers frown on globals, but they often prove useful in Access development. My suggestion is never to use a 'naked global' in a module. Instead, use public properties:

```
' Standard module (not a class or code behind form/report)
Private mgblStudent As Variant ' only visible/changeable within the module
Public Property Get gblStudent As Variant
    gblStudent = mgblStudent
End Property
Public Property Let gblStudent (varStudent As Variant)
    mgblStudent = varStudent
End Property
```

This way, your code works as before, but you can put breakpoints in the property to see when or if it is getting set or read.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to parse your question when you keep calling something "the variable" and not specifying which one your talking about. From what I can tell, you said recUserID is returning "Null" at the beginning of the question, but then you also said it is returning "0", which would be very different outcomes in this case. Regardless, I'm getting the impression that recUserID is either not being set correctly, or is no longer correct by the time you refer to it.

To troubleshoot this in my own code, I would start with something like what Cahaba Data suggested; Adding some message boxes:

```
If IsNull(Me.txtUser) Then
    MsgBox "Select User"
Else
    rs.FindFirst "[PersonnelID] = '" & Me.txtUser & "'"

    If rs.NoMatch Then
        MsgBox "User does not exist, please enter correct ID"
    Else
        recUserID = rs![UserID]
        MsgBox (recUserID) 'Add here
    End If
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form_AfterUpdate()
    MsgBox (recUserID) 'Add here    
    gblStudent = recUserID
    MsgBox (gblStudent) 'Add here
End Sub
```

Ideally you should see all 3 message boxes with the ID you expect. The first one that's wrong will help tell you where the problem is.